# How to use existing Cloud Formation template to generate SAM Local environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless, aws-sam-cli

I'm working on Data Lake project referring AWS Serverless Data Lake. 
https://github.com/awslabs/aws-data-lake-solution 
When I try to create SAM local template file I faced some problems with the configuration of existing resources(API Gateway, Coginto User Pool). 
Can I use the existing cloud formation template in order to generate the SAM local environment. Please let me know what are the changes I have to do to the existing template.

Cloud Formation Templates
https://github.com/awslabs/aws-data-lake-solution/tree/master/deployment